# Disable grey background "active" effect on mat-list-item in angular material sidenav

Tags: angular, angular-material

I use a `mat-sidenav` for navigation with a `mat-nav-list` and its `mat-list-items`.

```
<mat-sidenav-container class="sidenav-container">
    <mat-sidenav #sidenav mode="side" opened>

      <div class="sidenav-header">
        <img src="assets/logo.svg" alt="Logo" class="logo">
      </div>

      <mat-nav-list>
        <mat-list-item *ngIf="auth.isAuthenticated$ | async" routerLink="/link" routerLinkActive="is-active">
          <mat-icon>content_paste</mat-icon>
          <a mat-line>Test</a>
        </mat-list-item>
```

css:

```
mat-list-item {
  width: 280px;
  margin-left: 8px;
}

.is-active {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 40px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
}

mat-list-item:not(.is-active):hover {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  border-radius: 40px;
}

.mat-sidenav-container {
  background: transparent;
}
```

When I navigate via the url in the browser my styling works: The active item has the white, transparent background which I use because the website has a background image.

Howevern, when I just click on a list item the item is also active, but the background color is greyish. After a second click somewhere on the page (content-area e.g) the background color of the active menu item changes again to the correct color.

It seems that the mat-list-item has some default behaviour when an item is selected. Unfortunately I dont understand yet how to configure it.